# Incredibly high peak of traffic (Network In) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, network-traffic

I've found something extremely werid on my EC2 instance today; a peak on the "Network In" that goes beyond anything that had happened before, as you can see in the screenshot. Any idea about how to check some logs that help me understand what has caused this peak???

The apache access logs are normal,no more requests than normally; no clue where to look for more info related to this extremely weird event.

[image]

Comment: wow, 3.7 exa bytes, I hope you are not being charged by traffic ;)

Comment: You should create a ticket on AWS support (or a form post if you have basic support).  There has been a bug somewhere, I don't think they have hardware that can handle this peak. Hopefully it isn't out traffic ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with my EB instances. When I contacted the support they said that there is an issue with m4 instances and that those spikes are not accurate. Here is their response:

> There is an issue with m4 instances currently that are reporting some
>   non accurate spikes in Networking metrics. The cloudwatch team has
>   root-caused this issue to the on-server system that posts instance
>   performance metrics to CloudWatch, which is a separate from the
>   bandwidth accounting system that EC2 uses for billing. As a
>   workaround, you can view the correct metrics for your instance using
>   VPC Flow Logs. You will only be charged for actual data consumption.
>   The bug fix is complete and is being tested.

(I know that my reply 3 years after you asking the question is not very helpful for you, but I think that it may help others to know that sometimes issues are related to AWS and a contact with the support can easily confirm this or not)